# Org-Mode export table to latex with word wrap

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm trying to export a table from org-mode to latex and have dynamic line-breaks/word-wrapping, so whenever a cell exceeds a certain length, it should wrap to the next line.

This is what the latex code should look like:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.35\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}}
\end{tabular}
```

That seems to work when I manually edit the .tex file and convert to pdf again. Here is what my org code looks like:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment tabular :align p{0.35\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}
...
```

Which produces this latex output:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
...
```

How can I set the {|l|l|} to p{0.35\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth} in my org file?

Edit:

My solution was actually correct, the mistake was having the table in table.el format.

Comment: The `:align` spec that you have above worked for me: I get `\begin{tabular}{p{0.35\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}}` in the LaTeX file. What version of Org mode are you running?

Comment: @NickD You're correct. It does work. Turns out it doesn't when using a table.el table. Thank you for your help.

Comment: table.el tables are second-class citizens in Org mode unfortunately - there is very minimal support and AFAICT, currently the export is completely broken.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to the Org mode mailing list.

Comment: Nicolas Goaziou has fixed the bug that I reported: see [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/118da7d280a5fe474fc2b5a4e2d48ce5f910a29b) and  [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/97f1d8e34012c4181f587657a0c9cb39477ad997). This fixes the broken export but I don't think it does anything for your use case: table.el tables are still second-class citizens.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your effort.